# Error : "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee0234ff0)"

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this code and when I am running the App on the line with `"super.viewDidLoad()"`, I have the "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee0234ff0" error...
Can someone help me please?

On internet they say me that I have to connect my Developer Account, but I don't have one.

### This is the code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase



class SignUpController : UIViewController {



//Fonction pour scroller
private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView.self()
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
    return scrollView
    
}()

//MARK : Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var artistnameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmationPasswordTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var signupButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

//MARK : Properties


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewDidLoad()
    
    
//Add subviews
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(artistnameTextField)
    scrollView.addSubview(emailTextField)
    scrollView.addSubview(passwordTextField)
    scrollView.addSubview(confirmationPasswordTextField)
    scrollView.addSubview(signupButton)
    scrollView.addSubview(loginButton)
    
    //Design
    setupButtons()
    
    
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLogin" {
        let VCDestination = segue.destination as! LoginController
        VCDestination.myMail = emailTextField.text!
    }
    if segue.identifier == "showLogin" {
        let VCDestination = segue.destination as! LoginController
        VCDestination.myPassword = passwordTextField.text!
    }
}




//MARK : Private Methods
private func setupButtons() {
    signupButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 3
    loginButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
}

private func setupTextFieldManager() {
    artistnameTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

//MARK : Actions
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLogin", sender: nil)
}



@objc private func hideKeyboard() {
    artistnameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}



@IBAction func signupButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if artistnameTextField !== "" as AnyObject && emailTextField !== "" as AnyObject && passwordTextField !== "" as AnyObject && confirmationPasswordTextField.text == passwordTextField.text {
        
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                self.alertUserLoginError()
            } else {
                print ("Inscription en cours...")
                
                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                
                ref.child("users").child(userID!).setValue(["artistName": self.artistnameTextField.text])
                
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender:  self)
            }
        }
        
    } else {
        print("Veuillez remplir tous les champs.")
    }
}
@IBAction func loginButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Redirection vers l'écran de connexion...")
}

func alertUserLoginError() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Erreur", message: "Veuillez remplir tous les champs", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true)
}


}

extension SignUpController: UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    
    return true
}


}
```

Thanks

Comment: take out "viewDidLoad()" and leave "super.viewDidLoad()" your'e causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for the sake of brevity, here's a concept called "App Lifecycle" which by its nature is the methods that are called by the iOS system and in a specific order. Remember that computers can only run one thing at a time, per CPU. So it must go in an order of some sort. The iOS lifecycle events are as follows.

- loadView()
- viewDidLoad()
- viewWillAppear()
- viewDidAppear()
- didReceiveMemoryWarning()
- viewWillDisappear()
- viewDidDisappear()

Now bear in mind there are a few others depending on what you're doing but these are the most common ones.

With 90% of these lifecycle methods, there's something more that is going on in the background that you don't see. This is where the `super.methodName()` call comes into play. It allows you to add additional functionality at a given lifecycle event without losing any of the other functionality that is being provided by that method. Otherwise, you might lose something that is required to load the view. Eg, `super.methodName` retains all previous functionality.

Now, to your issue, you have the following lines of code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewDidLoad()
    //A bunch more code after this.
}
```

Looking at the Lifecycle methods, that are required in many cases, notice that you are calling `viewDidLoad()` inside of your `super.viewDidLoad` which means that your main thread gets stuck. It loops back through that method that called it, and then there it is again, another `viewDidLoad()` call. In turn, it loops, again, and again, and again, until it crashes. There is a time and a place for recursion, however, this is not one of them, and that's for a completely separate topic.

Ultimately your solution is to remove the `viewDidLoad()` method call after your `super.viewDidLoad()` and that will resolve the error that you're having.